# wordpressWarning: Cannot assign an empty string to a string offset in wp-includes\class.wp-scripts.php

Tags: wordpress

I am just config and integration of live wordpress package in local.I am just enter correct database in config file and change in database wp-option in url. But this error is display.How to fix this issue.I cannot know how to fix this issue

```
Warning: Cannot assign an empty string to a string offset in D:\xampp\htdocs\Nadesh\livereportlink\wp-includes\class.wp-scripts.php on line 447
```

Comment: This is a default WP class file, and at the mentioned line it seems to try and add localization data to a script. Impossible for anyone here to debug this any further, you will have to check on how your template/plugins use this kind of functionality, likely they are passing wrong data at some point.

Comment: ya its fine.Fixed thank you.  But one thing wordpress pacjkage in all pages like contact us and blogs page and dashboard page and others also working good. But in local that wordpress package admin access only working otherwise other page is not working. this error displayed 
 Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404     .how ti fix this issue

Comment: In case you are talking about “nice URLs”, it sounds like your .htaccess file might be missing or defect ... but with just a “not working” statement given in comments, almost as impossible to debug from here as the first issue ... If you need further help, then please go read [ask] first of all.